# Failed to import node.js version of contentful.js in Hydrogen/Remix

Tags: typescript, contentful, remix, shopify-hydrogen

I'm trying to import contentful.js with `import * as contentful from 'contentful';` in Remix but getting the error below. I'm doing this import in `server.ts` in order to add the contentful client to the loader context. contentful.js package.json specifies "main" and "browser" entries for built assets but I'm not sure why remix seems to be importing/bundling the browser version. This is remix v1.19.1 and contentful.js v^10.4.2.

> Error: Adapter 'http' is not available in the build
> at /Users/sambooka/work/epic-repos/wasabi/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.browser.min.js:1:27782
> at Le.Ee3 (/Users/sambooka/work/epic-repos/wasabi/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.browser.min.js:1:27961)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at i8 (/Users/sambooka/work/epic-repos/wasabi/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.browser.min.js:1:51678)
> at s16 (/Users/sambooka/work/epic-repos/wasabi/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.browser.min.js:1:51815)
> at o14 (/Users/sambooka/work/epic-repos/wasabi/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.browser.min.js:1:53980)
> at loader (/Users/sambooka/work/epic-repos/wasabi/app/root.tsx:57:17)
> at callRouteLoaderRR (/Users/sambooka/work/epic-repos/wasabi/node_modules/@remix-run/server-runtime/dist/esm/data.js:48:16)
> at callLoaderOrAction (/Users/sambooka/work/epic-repos/wasabi/node_modules/@remix-run/router/router.ts:3671:16)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)